# MariaDB Connector Removing Leading Zeros on ZEROFILL fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, connector, zerofill

I've just upgraded from MySQL 5.7 to MariaDB 10.3 and one functionality difference has me stumped.  I have an index field that is of the following type:

```
UserID | int(9) unsigned zerofill
```

If I execute the following query:

```
SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE UserID='000000003';
```

I get:

```
+-----------+
| UserID    |
+-----------+
| 000000003 |
+-----------+
```

If I use the MariaDB callback connector from Node.js I get the following:

```
[
        {
            "UserID": 3
        }
]
```

How do I prevent the MariaDB Connector/Node.js Callback API from stripping off the leading zeros from an index?  Right now I understand that I can pad every instance of a index reference within my API after all my queries, but this just seems... inefficient.

Is there a better way?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

node.js driver automatically evaluate value type. Since that's an int, 3 is the expected value.

If you explicitly want a string you can tell by sql, like query
`select cast (UserID AS CHAR) as UserID from User WHERE UserID='000000003';`

This will return

```
[
        {
            "UserID": '000000003'
        }
]
```

Comment: Nit: that’s not a valid JSON response.

Comment: Thank you very much for this -- this does work and it is more elegant to update the queries than it is to modify the results.  That said, while I appreciate that the field is an INT in the DB, if it is a zero padded INT the driver should return a zero padded result.  If that means returning it as a string, then fine.  This is a change in functionality between this and the older MySQL driver.  In any case, hope this helps someone else

@user2864740, my JSON response was just a clip of part of a larger response and Diego helpfully used the same clip.  You are correct that it is not valid JSON.